# how to sort data from GET request and order the data over 10

Tags: php, sorting

I am trying to perform a GET request. The data is in the format as follows:

```
key=STRING (5 letters upper and lowercase)
num=INTEGER (2 digit number from 1-99)

{"data":"key=XXXXX, num=xx, key=XXXXX, num=xx"}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init('link_here');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Not sure how to sort the data and output values over 10 only.

Thanks

Comment: Data is from db?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini as you can see clearly from the code, the data is from the result of a `curl()` request, and is in JSON format.

Comment: Yes, but how is the result displayed? An array?

Comment: Are you completely sure that the data you receive is just one big string? Also, what do you mean by output? Would a simple `echo` be enough?

Comment: hi data is an array (json ouput in browser when you visit the URL). yes, the data is just one big string in the above format (maybe around 100 values of "key" and "num")

Comment: We need more information here. Is there any relationship between key and num? What should be over 10, num?

Comment: @fromvega hi yes that is correct. num needs to be over 10. I pull the data and then its currently in an array. then a function to reorganize that data and only output values that are greater than 10. thanks

Answer (score 1):

your question is not clear We need more information,

but if you have a long string like this

```
{"data":"key=str50, num=50, key=str01, num=1, key=str15, num=15, key=str08, num=8, key=str99, num=99"}
```

just decode Json and explode your array like this

```
  $json    = '{"data":"key=str50, num=50, key=str01, num=1, key=str15, num=15, key=str08, num=8, key=str99, num=99"}';
  $encode  = json_decode($json);
  $data    = $encode->data;
  $explode = explode(",",$data);

  $array   = array();
  for($i=0;$i<sizeof($explode);$i++){
   if($i!=0)$i++;   
   $key      = explode("=",$explode[$i]);
   $val_next = explode("=",$explode[$i+1]);
   if($val_next[1]>10)
   $array[$key[1]]  = $val_next[1];
  }
   asort($array);
   print_r($array);
```

output is

```
Array ( [str15] => 15 [str50] => 50 [str99] => 99 )
```

Comment: thanks. that works. I tweaked it a bit, but your base was extremely helpful.